# Python3: IMAP -- cannot refer to tuples as elements

Tags: email, python-3.x, types, imap, email-attachments

I am working on a script to automatically login to a gmail account and write the email attachments. I have working code, but I am currently trying to refactor into a cleaner layout. I am having trouble figuring out how to convert tuples into variables that can be returned and then passed as arguments into subsequent functions. Is this even possible within this type of solution?

The login and filter work, but I get the following error, having to do with the typ, email_selection item:  NameError: name 'email_selection' is not defined

```
import email, getpass, imaplib, os, sys
from date_range import start_date, end_date

#enter_credentials
user_name = input('Enter your gmail username:\n')
password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password:\n')
imap_key = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)

#login_to_the_mailbox
def login_to_the_mailbox(imap_key, user_name, password):
    typ, login_attempt = imap_key.login(user_name, password)
    if typ != 'OK':
        print ('Not able to login!')
    else:
        print ('Login successful!')

#filter_the_mailbox
def filter_the_mailbox(imap_key, start_date, end_date):
    imap_key.select('Inbox')
    typ, email_selection = imap_key.search(None, "(UNSEEN)", "(SENTSINCE {0})".format(start_date), "(SENTBEFORE {0})".format(end_date))
    if typ != 'OK':
        print ('Not able to filter mailbox.')
    else:
        print ('Mailbox filtered!')
        return email_selection

#fetch_the_mail
def fetch_the_mail(imap_key, email_selection):
    for msg_id in email_selection[0].split():
        typ, message_parts = imap_key.fetch(msg_id, '(RFC822)')
        if typ != 'OK':
            print ('Error fetching mail.')
        else:
            print ('Mail fetched!')
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole stack trace, so we can *where* it is having troubel with email_selection?

Comment: And are you ABSOLUTELY sure you do not have a typo?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Max! Yes, I am sure I do not have a typo.

The issue is that it does not let me reference any variables defined with 'typ, ' in front of them. I am curious if there is a way to convert "typ, email_selection" into a variable that can be used as an argument in subsequent functions.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent then: you say filter_the_mailbox works.  fetch_the_mail uses typ, message_parts.  If that loop did not ever run, then message_parts will not be set.

Comment: Please provide a /complete/ code example that reproduces your problem, and the full stack trace so we can help.